# reading csv file in java start from line3

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

how do i make my csv file reader to read my csv file in java to an arraylist, start from line no.3 but line1 and line2, each of them is read to another arraylist. for example:

line1 -> arraylist1;
line2 -> arraylist2;
line3 - line'n' -> arraylist3

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited details, a simple implementation would do the following:

1. Open the CSV file
2. Read the first line

   1. Process the first line, and create a list.
3. Read the second line

   1. Process the first line, and create a list.
4. Read the next line

   1. Process the line, and create a list.
5. Repeat (4) until the end of the file.
6. Close the CSV file.

I would probably approach step 2-1, 3-1 and 4-1 by having separate methods, as I am guessing that the formatting for each of those 3 steps are different from each other.

The actual reading of the file may be using a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) which is able to read an entire line at a time by using the [`readLine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method, but this part may vary depending on the design of the application.

The processing of the line may be accomplished by splitting the line up by [`String.split(",")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and tossing the result into a `List`, but it would be brittle and error-prone, so a better method of breaking up the components would be needed, or it just may be a better approach to use a CSV manipulation library which can properly handle the edge-cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.

```
1. Organize your code like this:

  a. read line 1, 
  b. process and populate arraylist1, 
  c. read line 2,
  d. process and populate arraylist2,
  e. while readLine != null, 
     - process and populate arraylist3

2. Or like this:
  a. create a line counter `lineCnt`
  b. while readLine != null, 
     switch lineCnt++
     case 0
     - process and populate arraylist1
     case 1
     - process and populate arraylist2
     default
     - process and populate arraylist3
```